# html div got offset vertically inside parent div, why

Tags: html, css

[image]

Why is the "Input Status" div block got offset in its parents.

I did try toggle all its css attributes in the web inspector, it seems nothing fix the offset. Where did it come from?

Please have a look this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pengyanb/Lfvnr9y1/

```css
.containing_tab {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40pt;
    margin-bottom: 20pt;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
.status_tab {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
    font-family:'MS sans serif, Fallback, sans-serif';
    text-shadow:0 0 0 !important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40pt;
    background-color:green;
    border:1px blue solid;
}
.middle_padding {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border:1px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="containing_tab">
    <div class="status_tab">Input 1 Status</div>
    <div class="middle_padding"></div>
    <div class="status_tab">Input 2 Status</div>
</div>
```

I toggled all its css attribute in the web inspector,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the vertical-align property for inline elements defaults to [baseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align). Just change that to top:

```
.status_tab {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
    font-family:'MS sans serif, Fallback, sans-serif';
    text-shadow:0 0 0 !important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40pt;
    background-color:green;
    border:1px blue solid;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lfvnr9y1/1/)**

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got it now, "vertical-align" attribute is applied to the div itself not the the child elements it is containing, my bad.

Comment: One more question, why is the "middle_padding" div does not need the "vertical-align:top;" attribute  and still get aligned properly?

Comment: Because the middle padding div has no content. Put some text in it (without the vertical align and see it move).

Answer (score 0):

remove the height from the .containing_tab

```css
.containing_tab {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20pt;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
.status_tab {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
    font-family:'MS sans serif, Fallback, sans-serif';
    text-shadow:0 0 0 !important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40pt;
    background-color:green;
    border:1px blue solid;
}
.middle_padding {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border:1px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="containing_tab">
    <div class="status_tab">Input 1 Status</div>
    <div class="middle_padding"></div>
    <div class="status_tab">Input 2 Status</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to define the overall hight of that block.

Comment: Then you can try the add  top: -25px; position: relative; to the .status_tab